# Delete record with Event Scheduler

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

Just wanted to ask if this Event Scheduler works, also if once ran, it will continue to run as long as mySQL is running as a service?

```
    SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

    CREATE EVENT deleteVistors
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS'2013-08-13 04:00:00'
    DO 
    DELETE FROM tblwhitelist WHERE description = 'Vistors';
```

Also would this need a delimiter? I'm still unsure to what it actually is!

Hope you can help!

Comment: check this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html.  you can´t switch event_scheduler on if it´s been disabled in the main config. you should check  SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST to check if there is a event scheduler thread is running.

Comment: If i run this event scheduler, it will activate it, is that right?

Ive set it to 5 minutes and it works fine. So will i need to add the event in the main config? my-default.ini?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

> Not using ENDS means that the event continues executing indefinitely.

```
CREATE EVENT deleteVistors
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2013-08-13 04:00:00'
    -- !!! no *END*: will continue until you explicitly drop the event
    DO 
    DELETE FROM tblwhitelist WHERE description = 'Vistors';
```

---

For the second question:

> Also would this need a delimiter?

MySQL use the semi-colon as statement delimiter. For multi-line statements (`BEGIN ... END`, etc.) this could be confusing for your MySQL client as the `;` might appears *inside* those multi-line statements.

Here, you have only *one* `;` so you don't have to bother with that.

Comment: Okay thanks! 

Basically we wouldn't want the event to end. Is this still appropriate?